# the second elif condition doesnt get executed here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task
Given an integer, n, perform the following conditional actions:

If n is odd, print Weird

If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird

If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to20 , print Weird

If n is even and greater than20 , print Not Weird

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    if (n %2 != 0) or (n %2 ==0 and range(6,21)):
        print( 'Weird')
    elif(n %2 == 0 and range (2,6)) or (n %2 ==0 and n >20):
        print('Not Weird')
```

this is the output

[image]

Comment: `range(6, 21)` is always true, and at least one of `n % 2 == 0` or `n % 2 != 0` must always be true.  Your first if will therefore always be true and the elif can never happen.

Comment: What you wanted is `n in range(6,21)`, not just `range(6,21)`.

Comment: but doesn't the AND statement says both of them should be true if its even  does it falls under range(6,21)

Comment: @Fustavo The problem is that you don't have anything checking the "falls under" part.

Comment: Thanks Tim., that did solve the issue but can u elaborate  what was the difference between n in range(6,21) and range(6,21)

Comment: One uses `n`, the other doesn't? I'm not sure what elaboration you are looking for.

Comment: @Fustavo `if range(...):` means "if there are integers in this range". It doesn't check whether another integer is contained within that range.

Comment: Thanks, @wjandrea, that clears the doubt :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works:

```
...
if (n % 2 != 0) or (n in range(6, 21)):
    print('Weird')
elif (n in range(2, 6)) or (n > 20):
    print('Not Weird')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the below approach to get the required output.

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = int(input().strip())
    
    if n % 2 !=  0:
       print("Weird")

    else:
        if n >= 2 and n <= 5:
            print("Not Weird")
        elif n >= 6 and n <= 20:
            print("Weird")
        elif n > 20:
            print("Not Weird")
```